# sort alphabetically an imap.fetch in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, alphabetical

I'm trying to use Ruby's IMAP library to get a list of all the senders of email (the "from") and then sort it alphabetically, and then count how many emails from each person.

I'm getting hung up on step 1 - sorting alphabetically. This is the code I have and it returns a list of all the "from" values, but they are definitely not alphabetical.

Complete ruby novice here-- less than 1 week so pls be gentle.

```
mail_count = imap.search(["SINCE", @this_week.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")]).each do |message_id|
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
from_array = envelope.from[0].name.to_a
sorted_from = from_array.sort 
puts "#{sorted_from}"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
results = []
mail_count = imap.search(["SINCE", @this_week.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")]).each do |message_id|
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  from_array = envelope.from[0].name.to_a
  results << from_array
end
results.sort.each do |el|
  puts "#{el}"
end
```

Comment: this worked! Now I can move on to figuring out how to count the duplicates and then produce a sorted list of e1 : Number of Repeats